# one thread per block in cuda

Tags: c++, vector, cuda

If I have a sequence (or stream) of 2D vectors and I want to use one thread for each  2D vector, can I assign one block for each vector and one thread per block? Must I convert it first to one-dimensional array?  or the only thread can access the vector elements by the blockIdx.x and blockIdx.y?

and what will be the kernel launch parameters?

Assuming that vsize= number of the 2D vectors (which I want to use it as number of blocks)

is this will be correct:

```
mykernel<<vsize,1>>()
```

The computations on each vector are independent.
and my device compute capability is 2.1

Comment: Do you have to do that on the GPU? Cuda is fast because all the "threads" perform the same actions just on "neihboring" data regions.

Comment: yes I know, but I want to parallel my work on the vectors not on the elements of the vectors

Comment: I do not see a reason why using only one thread per block. If you want an individual thread to work on a different 2D vector, you can still populate a block with many threads and appointing each thread to work on a different 2D vector.

Comment: @Nada not 100% sure but I think you can do it, but not with `<< ... >>` but with `<<< ... >>>`. But first have a look at how many Streaming Multiprocessors your target gpu has got.

Comment: @JackOLantern, Thanks for replying, If I correctly understood what you meant, then I'll have one 3D block, right? otherwise, please explain to me how to do that, and if you have an example to clarify your suggestion it'll be highly appreciated.

Comment: @Micka, Thanks for replying, I think you are right, since I hade one answer below for the correct syntax I should use.

Comment: No, you will still have a one dimensional grid of blocks, but with many threads per block. It's not clear to me why using one thread per block is a constraint.

Comment: @JackOLantern because I have a collection of functions that must be executed in order at each block and these functions are coded to be applied in the whole vector, if I want to assign a thread for each element in the vector I should re-code all of the functions which may take long time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can launch one thread per block with CUDA.  It's generally not how you get performance out of the machine, because it leaves ~97% of the execution resources idle as that one thread is running.

If you want to launch one thread per block, this is the correct syntax:

```
mykernel<<<gridsize, 1>>>(...);
```

where `gridsize` is the number of blocks per grid you intend to launch.  Using one thread per block is often used to introduce CUDA to new programmers, but generally should not be used for performance-oriented code.

Under the above circumstances, every block will launch with a single thread, and that thread will have thread indices (`threadIdx.x`, `threadIdx.y`, and `threadIdx.z`) which are all zero.  The block indices (`blockIdx.x` etc.) will be determined by your `gridsize` variable.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer, actually I'm not too much interested in utilizing the resources, but it's fine if I can utilize them better!

Can I ask, if I have a real-time input, and don't know the number of blocks, what will be the correct syntax? or in that case I must use different way like streaming? I'm sorry for consulting in this, but I'm still newbie to CUDA.

Comment: If you know the number of blocks at kernel launch time, just set `gridsize` to that.  `gridsize` can be a runtime-set variable, it does not have to be known at compile-time.